# Avoid defining object value type with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Lets have following types example where I want to be able to define my custom object where key is flag name and value is flags body.

```
interface FlagModel {
    value: boolean;
}

interface GenericFlagsModel<T extends Record<string, FlagModel>> {
    flags: T
}

enum FLAG_NAMES {
    FLAG_FOO = 'flag-foo',
    FLAG_BAR = 'flag-bar'
}


type CustomFlagsModel = GenericFlagsModel<{
    [FLAG_NAMES.FLAG_FOO]: FlagModel,
    [FLAG_NAMES.FLAG_BAR]: FlagModel
}>
```

Looking at `CustomFlagsModel` you can see that I need to explicitly define `FlagModel` as a value. Is it possible to avoid this? For example like:

```
type CustomFlagsModel = GenericFlagsModel<{
    [FLAG_NAMES.FLAG_FOO],
    [FLAG_NAMES.FLAG_BAR]
}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following match your needs?

```
type CustomFlagsModel = GenericFlagsModel<Record<FLAG_NAMES, FlagModel>>
```

Comment: I found out that u dont need to use OR for this. Enum is enough.
`Record<FLAG_NAMES, FlagModel>`